# Retrieving List<T> collection from a REST method within a SharePoint 2013 Workflow

Tags: workflow, sharepoint-server, rest, visual-studio-2012, json

Here is the deal.. I have a REST method that returns `Generic.List<DTOSupervisor>` which has to be retrieved by using a HTTP Send and GetDynamicValueProperties components.

**My REST method signature:**

```
    [OperationContract]
    [WebGet(
        ResponseFormat = WebMessageFormat.Json,
        BodyStyle = WebMessageBodyStyle.Wrapped,
        UriTemplate = "GetSupervisorCollection/{employeeId}/{companyName}")]
    List<DTOSupervisor> GetSupervisorCollection(string employeeId, string companyName);
```

**REST Json output**

```
{"GetSupervisorCollectionResult":[
    {"Department":"IT","Email":"test@mail.com","EmployeeNumber":"00028","IsDepartmentHead":false,"LoginName":"domain\\nmuhammedh","Name":"Muhammedh Naufer"},
    {"Department":"IT","Email":"tariq@mail.com","EmployeeNumber":"00051","IsDepartmentHead":true,"LoginName":"domain\\tariq","Name":"Tariq Aziz"}
]}
```

My question is after I get the results as JSON, how can I convert it to a list of DTOSupervisor objects inside my workflow.

Comment: If your result comes out as shown in the "REST Json out" section that you posted, why can't you use the foreach loop activity on dynamicvalue to get your data out? What are you trying to do with that output?

Comment: I need to a create a Task for each supervisor.. Let me give it a shot and see.. Thanks...

Comment: Any tip on how to do the for each loop? I am unable to loop. It is only executing once.

Comment: Nice work! I wanted to post the answer to this, but was sidetracked with work - my apologies. You figured it out the best way though - through trial and error and now you won't forget how to do it. Keep it up!

Comment: Its alright brother. Thank you for your guidance. and so true.. Now i wont forget it inshaALLAH :D.. Cheers :)!

Comment: I am trying to do this very thing in my SharePoint 2013 workflow. Everything works until I try to get an individual value from the result. After the HttpSend I am getting back a similar response:
{"DoWorkResult":
[{"CompanyName":"ABC Company","CompanyNumber":"1"},
{"CompanyName":"EZ Company","CompanyNumber":"2"}]} I load the initial data into a DynamicValue variable based on the path of DoWorkResult. If I do a ToString on the DynamicValue I see the following:
[{"CompanyName":"ABC Company","CompanyNumber":"1"},
{"CompanyName":"EZ Company","CompanyNumber":"2"}] When I do a ForEach<DynamicValue>

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Found the solution...** Check out the steps below:

1. First retrieve the JSON (shown above) to a DynamicValue (i.e. ResponseDV) through an `HttpSend` activity.
2. Use an `GetDynamicValueProperties` activity and use the above DynamicValue as source and the properties setup will like shown below. 
   [image]

   ParsedDynamicValue is a new DynamicValue, and the setting the Path is the key here.
3. Now you can loop this DynamicValue using a `ForEach<T>` like shown below:
   [image]
4. Within the loop you can use another `GetDynamicValueProperties` activity to focus on each DynamicValue. Check the properties setup shown below:
   [image]

   DebugEmployeeId is a newly created string variable that will be populated every time the loop runs.