# How to get Json data from dictionary inside SharePoint Designer 2013

Tags: sharepoint-designer, designer-workflow

I am using WCF Service configured with "webHttpBinding" to a specific endpoint so it can return json once called from inside SharePoint Designer Workflow using "Call HTTP Web Service" Activity.

The return of the WCF endpoint is made of type of 
`List<WebSite>` where Website class looks

```
[DataContract]
public class WebSite
    {
        [DataMember]
        public string URL { get; set; }
        [DataMember]
        public string Name { get; set; }
        [DataMember]
        public bool Created { get; set; }
        [DataMember]
        public Guid Guid { get; set; }
    }
```

However when I am calling the endpoint from inside "Call Http" Activity the Response is saved inside dictionary as below

> {
>     "WebsiteCreationResult": [
>       {
>         "Created": true,
>         "Guid": "XXXXX-XXXX-XXX-XXXX-XXXXXXXX",
>         "Name": "YYYYYY",
>         "URL": "http://XXXX/sites/XXXX/YYYYYY"
>       }
>     ]
>   }

the value of the response dictionary was logged on Workflow History to confirm it, after that I used "**Get an Item from Dictionary**"Activity to extract "Created" value from the response Dictionary, but it never shows any value which suppose to be "ture" in the above example.
I've tired "WebsiteCreationResult/Created" and "Created" both didn't work.

Can anyone suggest to me what I should use to get the value from the dictionary.

BTW: I used PostMan to test the WCF restful function and it showed the above result exactly as it appears in History of the workflow!

Comment: Actually I found the Answer in the link below:
[enter link description here](http://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/174783/retrieving-listt-collection-from-a-rest-method-within-a-sharepoint-2013-workfl/175776)